# CSS type position and performance

Tags: performance, css

I know that positioning the most used class in the top of a big css-file, can decrease the rendering time, but is there any effect of positioning each line of code in a specific way?

Like:

```
        .class{
            width: 50px;
            position:absolute;
            z-index:3;
            height:50px;
        }
```

vs.

```
        .class{
            position:absolute;
            width: 50px;
            height:50px;
            z-index:3;
        }
```

Would it change anything or is it just a "prettier" way to code a css-file?
I'm developing a very big site, so every small gain is often worth some time.

Comment: No matter how big your site is, it is not worth scratching your head over something that turns out to save only 1 second per 100,000 requests once you actually profile it.

Comment: Although it's very good to think forward, most of the time such optimization will only be useless and not worth the time spent to establish a rule...

Comment: Not to mention CSS is typically cached by the browser, saving even more time on subsequent page loads.  In short, don't sweat this small stuff.  Long page loading times usually come down to database calls, and rendering page elements, not applying CSS.

Comment: "I know that positioning the most used class in the top of a big css-file, can decrease the rendering time" - Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Olly: Paul Irish: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HAqjyCH_LOE

Comment: Yeah you're all properly right. But its not about caching the file, but more about page-rendering. And CSS is a huge part of the rendering especially with CSS3.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific on where in the video that is stated? I’m not gonna watch half an hour now to find it …

Comment: Hmm sorry I cant remember. But he says that the fist 15% of the css-file should contain the classes used for every first pageview (which would mainly be structure and navigation)

Answer (score 0):

Even if it did effect it, the increment of time that is effected would be so small that it would not make hardly any difference. I wouldn't worry about something like that very much, but of course, if you feel it makes a difference, go for it!